# Texture appears in "Viewport Shading Solid Texture", but turns pink in "Viewport Shading Material Preview"

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, materials, shaders

[image]

I made a weapon in Blender, I created the texture and saved it on the computer and even though Blender knows where the texture is on my computer, the model turns pink. In this case, when it is in "Viewport Shading Material Preview", but when it is in "Viewport Shading Solid Texture" the texture appears without problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your shader output does not appear to be connected to a material output node.  You need to connect the BSDF output of the Principled Shader to the Surface input of a Material node, like this:

[image: Correctly connected nodes]

Comment: Okay, so how do I do this?

Comment: Use Shift-A to bring up the add menu and select output->material output.  Drop the new node to the right of the principled shader. then click on the green dot next to BSDF in the principled and drag to the green dot next to Surface on the Material output.

Comment: But make sure you don't already have a material output node that's just not connected.  In that case just do the drag